# How to get the last result from a MYSQL query using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have a simple articles table with IDs. I want to get the highest and lowest ids from the latest 10 results. For example, if there are 11 ids, the result should be 2 and 11 and if there are 4 ids, should be 4 and 1 and so on. I use PHP PDO statements.

```
$aid = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"); 
$aid->execute(); 
$row = $aid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
$lowest_article_id = $row[0];
$row = $aid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST);
$highest_article_id = $row[0];
```

The above will always return 11 if there are 11 records and 10 if there are 10 records. So, the query ignores the `PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST` part of the query.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a MAX or MIN on the selection of the ID and LIMIT it to 1?

Comment: I am curious, what can be use of such a query at all?

Comment: I think it means using a subquery? Also limiting to 1 means 1 result and i need 2 ids...the highest and the lowest from the latest 10 records...Also I need to know the pdo answer because I would use this in other queries as well...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some checking and from the docs it sounds like this should work. You need to enable cursor scrolling when you prepare the sql.

```
$aid = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)); 
$aid->execute(); 
$row = $aid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
$lowest_article_id = $row[0];
$row = $aid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST);
$highest_article_id = $row[0];
```

That being said it does not for me :/

I did more reading/testing and I found these two bug reports:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34625 (this one is from 2005 though and I am almost positive there is cursor functionality in MySQL these days).
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57623

Comment: The only question - who and why one would need such a functionality.

Comment: Yup! for me also, tried adding the cursor to the query but it's also not working...it seems like a bug though pdo for mysql should already support this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MIN and MAX functions in SQL to achieve this.

```
SELECT MIN(ID) min_ID, MAX(ID) max_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: I know the subquery solution but I want to avoid subqueries at all. Also I need to know the answer for PDO because it will useful for other queries as well..thanks

Comment: JW, I've tried this an on my mysql Db it won't work, but if you name the inner select with an alias it will work

Answer (score -1):

Or use the union command in sql

```
SELECT min(id) id FROM articles UNION SELECT max(id) id FROM articles;
```

This statement returns the two ids you need.

Comment: I don't know who keeps downvoting! I tried this query but it will output 1 and 11 although it should output 2 and 11. I have 11 ids numbered from 1 to 11 and want to select the highest and the lowest from the latest 10 rows which should mean id 11 the highest and id 2 the lowest...thanks :)

Comment: Also I need to know the PDO solution because it will help me in other queries...thanks :)

Comment: That's clear in my example is no limit and order. Thinking is allowed. Statement is statement. It doesn't matter wether in PDO or not.